# How to export an MXNet?

Tags: export, machine-learning, undocumented, neural-networks, mxnet-format

I was hoping there was some way to generate the .params and .json file needed to define an MXNet model, from a network trained using `NetTrain[]` in Mathematica. I was hopeful because I found these functions in the NeuralNetworks` package:

```
NeuralNetworks`ToMXNetSymbol
NeuralNetworks`ToMXNetJSON
```

You can use them on a net link this:

```
<< NeuralNetworks`;
net = NetInitialize@NetChain[{
     ConvolutionLayer[20, {5, 5}],
     ElementwiseLayer[Ramp],
     PoolingLayer[{2, 2}, {2, 2}],
     FlattenLayer[],
     DotPlusLayer[500],
     ElementwiseLayer[Ramp]
     }, "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {32, 32}}]];
ImportString[Normal@NeuralNetworks`ToMXNetJSON[net][[1]], "RawJSON"]
NeuralNetworks`ToMXNetSymbol[net]
```

Now, `ToMXNetJSON[]` returns a tuple, and it looks like the first element  *is the JSON for the symbol file*. But I don't know what the second element is, and I don't have a clue as to what `ToMXNetSymbol[]` is returning.

**Motivation:**  A solution to this would enable one to take any net from MMA and run it in C or Python with GPU inference!

Comment: Have you seen [`"WLNet"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/WLNet.html)? It can be found in the [Neural Networks](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NeuralNetworks.html) guide.  It is not JSON but is a way to serialise the net.

Comment: @Edmund yes I know about wlnet, but I need the net in mxnet.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question - I've wondered often the same thing

Comment: I edited the tags to include [tag:undocumented] but I had to drop one of the others to make room for it; I chose [tag:json].  Please let me know if you find this acceptable.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Wizard that's great

Comment: The params file is some sort of NDArray file.

Answer (score 27):

It seems the [model file in MXNet (checkpoint)](http://mxnet.io/api/python/model.html#save-the-model) is defined by two files: a ".json" file and a ".params" file. The json file contains the definition of the network, and the params file contains the actual weight and bias of each neuron. The params file is in the binary format of MXNet's [NDArray](http://mxnet.io/tutorials/python/ndarray.html) representation.

Thus, to export a network in Mathematica to MXNet, we need to generate these two files. The json file can be generated easily with the ``` NeuralNetworks``ToMXNetJSON ```. The param file can be generated using the ``` MXNetLink``NDArrayExport ```. Here is an example of this process using MNIST example in the documentation.

We first load the packages

```
<< MXNetLink`;
<< NeuralNetworks`;
<< GeneralUtilities`;
```

and define the network

```
net = NetChain[{
   ConvolutionLayer[20, {5, 5}],
   ElementwiseLayer[Ramp],
   PoolingLayer[{2, 2}, {2, 2}],
   ConvolutionLayer[50, {5, 5}],
   ElementwiseLayer[Ramp],
   PoolingLayer[{2, 2}, {2, 2}],
   FlattenLayer[],
   DotPlusLayer[500],
   ElementwiseLayer[Ramp],
   DotPlusLayer[10],
   SoftmaxLayer[]},
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", Range[0, 9]}],
  "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {28, 28}, "Grayscale"}]
  ]
```

[image]

Then we train the network

```
resource = ResourceObject["MNIST"];
trainingData = ResourceData[resource, "TrainingData"];
testData = ResourceData[resource, "TestData"];
trained = 
 NetTrain[net, trainingData, ValidationSet -> testData, 
  MaxTrainingRounds -> 3]
```

We will now export the trained network into the MXNet's model files.

The json file can be exported using `ToMXNetJSON`

```
jsonPath = "~/Downloads/MNIST-symbol.json";
Export[jsonPath, ToMXNetJSON[trained][[1]], "String"]
(* "~/Downloads/MNIST-symbol.json" *)
```

The second part of `ToMXNetJSON[trained]` contains the weights of our network. However, the weights are in Mathematica's [`RawArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RawArray.html) format, so we need to convert those into MXNet's NDArray format. Also we will drop the encoder layer, and change the names of the layers to comply with the convention

```
paraPath = "~/Downloads/MNIST-0000.params";
ass = KeyDrop[ToMXNetJSON[trained][[2]], ".Inputs.Input"];

f[str_] := 
 If[StringFreeQ[str, "Arrays"], str, 
  StringReplace[
   StringSplit[str, ".Arrays."] /. {a_, b_} :> 
     StringJoin[{"arg:", a, "_", b}], {"Weights" -> "weight", 
    "Biases" -> "bias"}]]

NDArrayExport[paraPath, NDArrayCreate /@ KeyMap[f, ass]]
(* "~/Downloads/MNIST-0000.params" *)
```

Now the two files "MNIST-symbol.json" and "MNIST-0000.params" can be used to load the network in MXNet.

To verify that the files are correct, we can use `ImportMXNetModel` to import MXNet model files we just generated.

```
trained2 = 
 NetGraph[{ImportMXNetModel[jsonPath, paraPath]}, {}, 
  "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {28, 28}, "Grayscale"}], 
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", Range[0, 9]}]]
```

[image]

And we see that the network from the MXNet's model files produces the same predictions as our original network:

```
testsample = RandomSample[testData, 100];

(trained[Keys[#], "Probabilities"] & /@ 
   testsample) == (trained2[Keys[#], "Probabilities"] & /@ testsample)
(* True *)
```

**Edit for version 11.1**

It seems that the structure of the implementation of neural network has been updated in 11.1. The trained weight is no longer in the ``` NeuralNetworks``ToMXNetJSON ```. The trained weight can be accessed using ``` NeuralNetworks``ToNetPlan ```.

```
plan = ToNetPlan[trained]
```

[image]

So to export the weight, we can do

```
NDArrayExport[paraPath, NDArrayCreate /@ KeyMap[f, plan["WeightArrays"]]]
```

Comment: This no longer works in 11.1 would you be able to update your answer, please? I believe `ToMXJSON` replaces `ToMXNetJSON` and `ToMXNetJSON[trained][[2]]` should be `ToMXJSON[trained][[3]]`, but `ImportMXNetModel[]` is still failing for me...

Comment: The import call gives the warning: ''Inferred inconsistent shapes for array "Weights" (a length-4 vector versus a rank-4 tensor).''

Comment: Thanks for the update! Would you be able to give a working example for either NetModel["SqueezeNet V1.1 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data", "EvaluationNet"] and NetModel["GloVe 300-Dimensional Word Vectors Trained on Wikipedia and Gigaword-5 Data", "EvaluationNet"]?

Comment: For some nets (liek GloVe) we need to encode the SpecialArrays and FixedArrays into the mxnet files, how might that be done?

Comment: @user5601 I think you can just use the pretrained network for MXNet at https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet-model-gallery. I think this pretrained network is also what Mathematica uses in the `NetModel` too. For GloVe, the trained network is an embedding layer, and the weights can be extracted directly using `NetExtract[net, "Weights"]`

Comment: Your original answer was great, but I'd really appreciate another few written out examples for those nets with more complicated layer types and special and fixed arrays. The 500 points was a lot for me to offer! Thanks

Comment: I'll go ahead and accept your solution but I still would greatly appreciate an extra example or two!

Comment: @user5601 Thanks! I will try to add more examples once I get a better understanding of the internal implementation of neural network framework in Mathematica.

Comment: I sent the bounty your way, thanks for following up on this

Comment: I take it you weren't able to figure this out yet

Comment: But you haven't test the net in MXNet.Actually,it leads problem,ref https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155069/example-of-netchain-running-in-mxnet-cause-error

Comment: @partida I suggest waiting until 11.2 to test. The underline implementation has been changed quite a lot, and it's not worth spending time now and later find out the code breaks in the new release.

Comment: @xslittlegrass Thank you for your suggestion,I do something else and wait the new release...

Comment: @xslittlegrass The 11.2 is release,problem remains

Comment: @partida I think it should be regarded as a bug then. Maybe you should report it to Wolfram.

Comment: Supposedly  [Export now supports this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MXNet.html)... however, I have an encoder on my net and even though the doc says it will automatically drop this, it doesnt and the export fails

Comment: Also the "update" no longer works... the json file is just NetChain[<len_net_chain>]

Comment: Hello,`ToMxPlan` is renamed as `ToNetPlan` and `plan["ArgumentArrays"]` is renamed by `plan["WeightArrays"]`

Comment: @partida I updated the post. Thanks!