# Simple example of NetGraph running in MXNet?

Tags: export, machine-learning, interoperability, neural-networks, mxnet-format

There is an great example of [exporting a NetGraph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133857/how-to-export-an-mxnet) (that was trained in Mathematica) into the MXNet's format.

However, I think there's a bug or something is wrong with the answer, because once exported the file refuses to load into mxnet.

I've cleaned the old answer (which is broken) into something that works:

```
<< MXNetLink`;
<< NeuralNetworks`;
<< GeneralUtilities`;
net = NetChain[{ConvolutionLayer[20, {5, 5}], ElementwiseLayer[Ramp], 
   PoolingLayer[{2, 2}, {2, 2}], ConvolutionLayer[50, {5, 5}], 
   ElementwiseLayer[Ramp], PoolingLayer[{2, 2}, {2, 2}], 
   FlattenLayer[], DotPlusLayer[500], ElementwiseLayer[Ramp], 
   DotPlusLayer[10], SoftmaxLayer[]}, 
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", Range[0, 9]}], 
  "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {28, 28}, "Grayscale"}]]
resource = ResourceObject["MNIST"];
trainingData = ResourceData[resource, "TrainingData"];
testData = ResourceData[resource, "TestData"];
trained = 
 NetTrain[net, trainingData, ValidationSet -> testData, 
  MaxTrainingRounds -> 3]
jsonPath = "~/MNIST-symbol.json";
paraPath = "~/MNIST-0000.params";
Export[jsonPath, ToMXJSON[trained][[1]], "String"];
f[str_] := 
  If[StringFreeQ[str, "Arrays"], str, 
   StringReplace[
    StringSplit[str, ".Arrays."] /. {a_, b_} :> 
      StringJoin[{"arg:", a, "_", b}], {"Weights" -> "weight", 
     "Biases" -> "bias"}]];
plan = ToMXPlan[trained];
NDArrayExport[paraPath, 
 NDArrayCreate /@ KeyMap[f, plan["ArgumentArrays"]]]
```

Now, yes we can load it back into MMA alright, but when it comes time to try it with MXNet for reals, we start hitting various snags when trying to load the symbol/params into a module so we can actually use the network:

```python
import mxnet as mx (* python code that loads an runs the model *)
sym, arg_params, aux_params = mx.model.load_checkpoint('MNIST', 0)
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
batch_size = 2
iter = mx.io.NDArrayIter(mnist['data'][:6], mnist['target'][:6], batch_size)
mod = mx.mod.Module(symbol=sym, context=mx.cpu(), data_names=['Input'], label_names=None)
mod.bind(for_training=False, data_shapes = [('Input', (batch_size, 1, 28, 28))])
mod.set_params(arg_params, aux_params)
print(mod.predict(iter))
```

[image]
[image]

I've heard this functionality is coming in future versions, but I'd really like to start using the nets I've trained in a real setting. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that the internal structure of the neural network framework is under constant development. Many things have changed from version 11.0 to 11.1.1. It would be best if this answer can be addressed by wolfram employees who knows more about the internal structure.

Comment: same problem.Even the net is simple.`net = NetInitialize@NetChain[{5, 3}, "Input" -> 2];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my question [Example of NetChain running in MXNet cause Error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155069/example-of-netchain-running-in-mxnet-cause-error) and **[re-post in Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1187520?p_p_auth=UgrEK46y)**

Thanks for Mike Sollami gave nice code to get the perfect result.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that, it is change the way of exporting by Mathematica and it is fully explained in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162479/54287