# How can I import Mathematica's NetModel in MXNet-python and predict the image and get the same result/probability?

Tags: machine-learning, mxnet-format

```
import os
import mxnet as mx
import numpy as np
import PIL

sym = mx.symbol.load("LeNet.json")
nd = mx.nd.load("LeNet.params")


def pred_LeNet(img_url):
# manual 'NetEncoder' step
img = PIL.Image.open(img_url)
img = img.convert('L')
img = img.resize((28, 28), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)# anti-alias
img = np.asarray(img, dtype=np.uint8)
mxnet_img = 1 - (img / 255.)
mxnet_img = mxnet_img.reshape(28, 28)
# print mxnet_img
img_inputND = mx.nd.array([[mxnet_img]])
nd["Input"] = img_inputND
e = sym.bind(mx.cpu(), nd)
out = e.forward()
print 'out', out[0].asnumpy()

return np.argmax(out[0].asnumpy())

pred_LeNet("/home/sysadmin/Pictures/8.jpeg")
```

The result is

```
out [[  2.91155395e-03   6.59108309e-07   1.04671001e-01   1.09607197e-06
1.18503478e-04   8.91811967e-01   1.23256556e-04   5.59793705e-07
3.85429324e-08   3.61442071e-04]]
```

In Mathematica 11.2, mxnet version is 0.9.5, so I get my result above in 0.9.5.

The result in Mathematica is , the sample picture is 8 in Basic Examples in HelpPage of NetModel.

```
<|0 -> 7.28386*10^-13, 1 -> 1.8159*10^-16, 
 2 -> 2.15518*10^-12, 3 -> 3.2635*10^-12, 4 -> 9.74528*10^-15, 
 5 -> 6.61678*10^-10, 6 -> 3.45442*10^-13, 7 -> 3.57894*10^-20, 
 8 -> 1., 9 -> 2.42621*10^-12|>
```

---

Update

1@
We should `Export["8.color_negate.jpg", ColorNegate[trainingData[[53433, 1]]]]`

2@
    `img=PIL.Image.open(img_url)
     img = img.convert('L')`
     change the image a bit

3@I have bad result in 
`net = NetModel[
  "Inception V1 Trained on Extended Salient Object Subitizing Data"]`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple example of NetGraph running in MXNet?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146450/simple-example-of-netgraph-running-in-mxnet)

Comment: @partida Hi, I found two problem. one is  that `img=PIL.Image.open(img_url)` changes a bit for the sample. The model is sensitive to the tiny changes of pixel, the linked post use mnist dataset use matrix without ImageProcessing... see update

Comment: If you want to test MNIST in mxnet, try Matrix.You can also load images with size 28*28,otherwise it may not get a good result

Comment: @partida not test mnist, consider a real project, we recognize the image, we do not have the matrix, we should get the matrix from the image.

Comment: I think you can load these imges using Mathematica, then try to recognize it correctly.And make sure the python get same matrix from image as Mathematica does

Comment: @partida I've tried that mathematica can load the image correctly, the keypoint is how to make python get the same matrix from the image.

Comment: So this is another question, **how to make python get the same matrix from the image as mma**.If this works,everything works

Comment: @partida yes, updated my title.

Comment: I tried.`file = Export["flower.jpg", Import["ExampleData/rose.gif"]];imgData1 = 
  ExternalEvaluate["Python", 
   "from PIL import Image;import numpy as np;im=Image.open('flower.jpg');im_resized=im.resize((28, 
28),Image.NEAREST);(np.asarray(im_resized,
dtype=np.uint8)/255.).tolist()"];imgData2 = 
  ImageData[
   ImageResize[Import["flower.jpg"], {28, 28}, 
    Resampling -> "Nearest"]];Max@Abs@Flatten[imgData1 - imgData2]` sill got 0.0352941,I don't know why