# How to delete the parameter of a Neural Network?

Tags: neural-networks

Mathematica Neural Networks based on `MXNet`.
And there is [lots of model in MXNet(MXNet Model Zoo)](http://mxnet.io/model_zoo/).

For example,I follow a tutorial [An introduction to the MXNet API — part 4](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/an-introduction-to-the-mxnet-api-part-4-df22560b83fe),
It uses [Inception v3(net using MXNet)](http://data.dmlc.ml/models/imagenet/inception-bn/).

I can use this code to load this *pretrained model*

```
<< NeuralNetworks`;
net = ImportMXNetModel["F:\\model\\Inception-BN-symbol.json", 
                       "F:\\model\\Inception-BN-0126.params"];
labels = Import["http://data.dmlc.ml/models/imagenet/synset.txt", "List"];
incepNet = NetChain[{ElementwiseLayer[#*255 &], net}, 
            "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {224, 224}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"}], 
            "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", labels}]]
```

[image]

```
 TakeLargestBy[incepNet[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/893F0.jpg"],
  "Probabilities"], Identity, 5]//Dataset
```

[image]

```
Dynamic@Column[{#, incepNet[#]} &@CurrentImage[]]
```

[image]

```
FileByteCount[Export["Inception v3.wlnet", incepNet]]/2^20.
(*44.0188 MB*)
```

I want to share this model to others, but it's too big (about 44 MB) because there are lots of parameters in this pretrained model.

If I only want to share this **model structure** to others,I think `deNetInitialize` is necessary.

[image]

You can see `UninitializedEvaluationNet` only need ***very little memory***.

In order to share nets like `UninitializedEvaluationNet`, can we define a `deNetInitialize` function?

Comment: There is an internal function which does precisely this: NeuralNetworks`NetDeinitialize

Comment: @dan7geo wow! interesting...Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The weights in the neural network are stored in the form of `RawArray`. This can be seen by comparing their full form

```
NetInitialize@ConvolutionLayer[1, {2}, "Input" -> {1, 3}] // InputForm
(* ConvolutionLayer[<|"Type" -> "Convolution", 
  "Arrays" -> <|"Weights" -> RawArray["Real32", {{{0.4258739650249481, -0.9216004014015198}}}], 
    "Biases" -> RawArray["Real32", {0.}]|>, "Parameters" -> <|"OutputChannels" -> 1, "KernelSize" -> {2}, "Stride" -> {1}, 
    "PaddingSize" -> {0}, "Dilation" -> {1}, "Dimensionality" -> 1, "InputChannels" -> 1, "$GroupNumber" -> 1, "$InputSize" -> {3}, 
    "$OutputSize" -> {2}|>, "Inputs" -> <|"Input" -> TensorT[{1, 3}, RealT]|>, "Outputs" -> <|"Output" -> TensorT[{1, 2}, RealT]|>|>, 
 <|"Version" -> "11.1.1"|>] *)

ConvolutionLayer[1, {2}, "Input" -> {1, 3}] // InputForm
(* ConvolutionLayer[<|"Type" -> "Convolution", "Arrays" -> <|"Weights" -> TensorT[{1, 1, 2}, RealT], 
    "Biases" -> Nullable[TensorT[{1}, RealT]]|>, "Parameters" -> <|"OutputChannels" -> 1, "KernelSize" -> {2}, "Stride" -> {1}, 
    "PaddingSize" -> {0}, "Dilation" -> {1}, "Dimensionality" -> 1, "InputChannels" -> 1, "$GroupNumber" -> 1, "$InputSize" -> {3}, 
    "$OutputSize" -> {2}|>, "Inputs" -> <|"Input" -> TensorT[{1, 3}, RealT]|>, "Outputs" -> <|"Output" -> TensorT[{1, 2}, RealT]|>|>, 
 <|"Version" -> "11.1.1"|>] *)
```

To remove the weights, we only need to replace the `RawArray` with the corresponding place holders. Here is a solution using string manipulation

```
netUnInitialize[net_] := 
 Activate@Replace[
   ToExpression[
    StringReplace[
     ToString[InputForm[net]], {"NetChain" -> "Inactive[NetChain]", 
      "NetGraph" -> "Inactive[NetGraph]", 
      "RawArray" -> "Inactive[RawArray]"}]], 
   Inactive[RawArray][x_, y_] :> 
    NeuralNetworks`TensorT[Dimensions[y], 
     NeuralNetworks`RealT], ∞]

FileByteCount[Export["~/Downloads/incept.wlnet",netUnInitialize[incepNet]]]
(* 40877 *)
```