# Is it possible to fix the weight of a certain layer during neural network training?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

As suggested by the title, is it possible to fix some part of the neural network while training?

Since Mathematica provides a way to extract part of a neural network and combine it with some layers to make a new one:

```
newNet = NetChain[{Take[oldNet, 3], 10, Ramp, 10}]
```

It would be very helpful to fix the layers taken from the old network. In this way one can reuse the neural network and investigate how transferrable are features in the neural network (c.f. https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.1792).

Comment: Is `LearningRateMultipliers` what you are looking for? And [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141150/1364) are examples of transfer learning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `LearningRateMultipliers` supports using different learning rates with different layers. When setting the learning rate of a particular layer to None, the weight of that layer will be fixed during training.

You can have a look at the example in the documentation of `LearningRateMultipliers`.

In that example, `net` is constructed from part of the network trained for MNIST

```
net = NetChain[Join[Drop[Normal[lenet], -2],
   {LinearLayer[], SoftmaxLayer[]}],
  "Input" -> enc, "Output" -> dec]
```

Then at the training time, only the newly added linear layer is allowed to change. All the other layers are fixed by setting the learning rate to None.

```
trained = 
 NetTrain[net, trainingData, 
  MaxTrainingRounds -> Quantity[10, "Seconds"], 
  LearningRateMultipliers -> {-2 -> 1, _ -> None}, 
  ValidationSet -> Scaled[0.1]]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the helpful answer!

Comment: @xslittlegrass, Why `LearningRateMultipliers -> {-2 -> 1, _ -> None}` and not `LearningRateMultipliers -> { _ -> None, -2->1}`? Aren't you undoing the first `LearningRateMultipliers` assigment?

How can one transfer some layers without their trained values?

Comment: @mpourrah We need to use `{-2 -> 1, _ -> None}` because the rules are matched with the order. If you use `{ _ -> None, -2->1}` then the first rule is always matched so that the learning rate is 0 for all layers.

Comment: @mpourrah You can use ``NeuralNetworks`NetDeinitialize`` to remove the weights. See more [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/151591/1364).