# Transfer Learning: How to take certain layers from a pre-trained neural net, add it to a new net, and keep its variables fixed?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

How can one copy specified layers from a pre-trained neural network and add them to another trained neural net?

For instance,

```
net1 = NetModel["LeNet Trained on MNIST Data"]
```

[image: net1]

and `net2` has a similar structure but it has been trained on a different dataset (however, to keep things simple for this question we can set `net2 = net1`). How should one go about taking layers 4, 5, 6 from `net1` and replace layers 4, 5, 6 in `net2`, fix their variable so they would not change during the training process, and train `net2` on some dataset?

Comment: Does [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153954/1364) or [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141150/1364) answer your question?

Comment: @xslittlegrass, The first link help Thanks. Should I delete this question then?

Comment: How can I transfer layers WITHOUT their variables, i.e. just the layer structure?